# Something is deleting image files from getExternalFilesDir()?

Tags: android

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is going on with my app. Various users have reported that the app generated image files are gone. However, the database data isn't gone and it is stored at the common location `Context.getDatabasePath()`. Also, all folders are kept intact just images missing.

So I'm thinking there is some routine in Android causing this? Or some other app cleaning up *.png files? I know my app isn't removing them since I don't have any routine to recursively remove all image files.

Also, the parent folder has the .nomedia file so all child folders shouldn't be touched by the gallery right?

I'm storing these files inside the following path structure where %d is a unique number:

> getExternalFilesDir()/projects/p_%d/l_%d/%d.png

This is how I get the projects path creates:

```
public static File getProjectsDir(Context context)
{
    // External app directory handled by the OS. Meaning that when the app is uninstalled all
    // the data inside this folder will be also removed.
    File appRoot = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if (null == appRoot) {
        Log.e(TAG,"getProjectsDir() -> External storage not accessible!");
        return null;
    }

    File projectsDir = new File(appRoot, "projects");

    // create projects directory
    if (!projectsDir.exists()) {
        if (!projectsDir.mkdir()) {
            Log.e(TAG,"getProjectsDir() -> Unable to create projects folder!");
            return null;
        } else {
            File noMediaFile = new File(projectsDir, ".nomedia");
            if (!noMediaFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    if (!noMediaFile.createNewFile()) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"getProjectsDir() -> no media file failed to be created!");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"getProjectsDir() -> no media file failed to be created!",e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return projectsDir;
}
```

Comment: "So I'm thinking there is some routine in Android causing this?" -- I am not aware of anything in standard Android that would delete files from there other than by user request (e.g., "clear data" in Settings). Cache directories can get cleared automatically, at least in low-storage situations. "Or some other app cleaning up *.png files?" -- with external storage, that is certainly possible. You might consider adding some automated check for this condition in your app, then logging it where you can pick up device details (e.g., a silent exception in ACRA), to look for common characteristics.

Comment: "the parent folder has the .nomedia file so all child folders shouldn't be touched by the gallery right?" -- that's a convention at best.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your help. So "CLEAR CACHE" doesn't remove the projects images I can confirm. Also, "CLEAR DATA" causes database and project files to be removed. So The user isn't doing any of those or the OS.

Comment: I have analytics for tracking crashes such as ACRA... But what kind of automated check you suggest I do? Something like listening for file removals? Some details would be great! Thx.

Comment: "But what kind of automated check you suggest I do?" -- when your app starts, validate the database against the filesystem. If the database says that there should be an image where `%d` is 123, and there is no such image, then something deleted that image behind your back. If *none* of the images are there, then all the images were deleted, and that may be worth logging.

Comment: @CommonsWare this has happened to my app too. there have been so much report about this recently from my users and despite all my effort I couldn't find the reason behind it. I have some "jpg" files and also some "mp4" files in different folders inside getExternalFilesDir and those get deleted without any reasonable cause (apparently) !

Comment: @LordSepid: Do you have any commonalities in the reports (e.g., they are all using devices from one manufacturer)?

Comment: @CommonsWare no, different manufacturers (like Huawei & HTC) with different OS versions (from android 6 to 7.1). even one of them has LineageOS 14.1

Comment: I'm using getExternalFilesDir(null) with some custom dirs in it like "pics", not the predefined subdirectories like "Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES". could this be the problem ?

Comment: @LordSepid: There should be no problem there. Perhaps these users have installed some poorly-written "cache cleaner" apps that are deleting these files. The benefit of `getExternalFilesDir()` over `getFilesDir()` is that the user and other apps have access to the files. The problem with `getExternalFilesDir()` over `getFilesDir()` is that the user and other apps have access to the files. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @CommonsWare after a few tests it happened to two of my phones too |':

Comment: and I don't have any kind of cleaning app installed on them. I guess I should go for a direct folder inside internal sdcard like other apps e.g. whatsapp & etc.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this issue? I'm experiencing something similar with ```.zip``` files.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48128014/4826571), it appears that the DownloadManager deletes any files from third-party apps that haven't been accessed (i.e. "UI-Visible") in over 7 days.

The workaround would be to rename the file after it's downloaded so the DownloadManager can no longer track it.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for that reference.