# Downloaded files get deleted automatically

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager

In my app, there are a few files that users can download. The files get downloaded **via the android download manager**. But, since a few weeks now, hundreds of users have been complaining that their files automatically keep deleting every 8-12 days, without them even uninstalling the app. (There might be many more users who haven't bothered to complain about the same.)

Now, there could be a number of user-specific reasons why that would happen on a few devices. But considering the huge number of users, it seems that I might have been doing something wrong.

Why would the system/download manager delete the files automatically? Is there a way to inform the system or the download manager to not delete certain files? Or should I just settle with renaming the files after downloading, so as to unlink them from the download manager, and hope that the problem gets solved with just that?

Edit:

Here's the code that I use to download the files:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(trackLink));
request.setTitle(trackTitle);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Tracks", trackTitle + ".mp3");
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Where are you saving these files? And what use of those files in your application? And yes, can you please share the code segment you're using to download and save your files?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have edited my question with the code I use to download files. These files are mp3 tracks that can be played in the app.

Comment: So do you show "File not found" or something like this when you try to play a corrupted file??

Comment: There's a 'Download' button that converts into a 'Play' button after downloading. And when this auto-deletion happens, the button turns into the 'Download' button, again; stating that the file was deleted, and needs to be downloaded again.

Comment: Any clue, what could be done? @ReazMurshed

Comment: Nope. I tried writing a comment but the comment was too big. I posted my thoughts as an answer later.

Comment: did you find out anything, Sagar?

Comment: Hi @Wayne, the chosen answer helped me to debug the issue; and to fix the issue I ended up downloading the file and simply renaming it, hence preventing Android OS from keeping track of the usage of the file.

Comment: have u found any solution? I also have  same issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I also came across this issue. Looking at the source for `DownloadIdleService` it appears that if the download are set to not be visible in the UI they're deleted after 7 days as they're considered "stale".
Here's the javadoc from`DownloadIdleService`:

```
/**
 * Remove stale downloads that third-party apps probably forgot about. We
 * only consider non-visible downloads that haven't been touched in over a
 * week.
 */
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadIdleService.java#110

Comment: Is there any way to stop these deletion?

Comment: Best bet is to probably download using a temporary file name and rename it once the download has finished.

Answer (score 6):

There is a bigger problem starting in Android Q where value set by [setVisibleInDownloadsUi](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setVisibleInDownloadsUi(boolean)) is ignored and it is false by default. The files will be deleted after a week. You can test it by: download file, change date in calendar by 2 months for example, call this in terminal:

**adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f com.android.providers.downloads -100**

It starts job from [DownloadIdleService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadIdleService.java#110) where old and forbidden files are deleted. You can see in logcat (set no filter) that DownloadManager try to delete your files.

To prevent from that you can:

- download files to **`Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String) with Environment#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`** - this is the only path starting in Android Q where downloads are visible and should not be deleted
- change file name after downloading (in DownloadedReceiver for example)

Comment: I was going to get mad about this issue, many users have been complaining about this. You have exactly described what the problem is in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It was too big for a comment to I'm just putting it as an answer.

I don't have any clue yet why the files are missing or getting deleted over a period of time - which a bit strange. But I had to do something similar and never experienced something like this. So I though I might share what I have done in that case.

I preferred to keep the downloaded files in the internal storage which the application holds rather than keeping it in the external storage. For example, the file path where I used to save the downloaded files is something like...

```
/data/data/" + "com.example.myapplication" + "/musicfiles/
```

So what I did right after downloading is telling the media scanner about the new file so that it is immediately available to the user. So as I was downloading the file using an `AsyncTask` I had to run the scanner in the `onPostExecute` method like this after a successful download.

```
protected void onPostExecute() {

    if(downloadCompletedSuccessfully) {

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

So in your case, I think its not might be the issue that the Download button is not visible due to the unavailability of the file downloaded. It might happen if the media scanner fails to find the file in the file system as well. So you might consider giving it a try.

I don't know if clean master or some softwares like that cleans junk files every now and then if they are in external storage. You might consider investigate those as well.

Comment: Thanks Reaz, but I have nothing to do with the media scanner. In fact, I also have a .nomedia file where my files get downloaded, so as the media scanner purposefully ignores it. I will look into the cleaner apps like the clean master one. Surely, one of those famous apps must be the culprit here.