# Files in Android Scoped Storage Get Randomly Deleted

Tags: android, osmdroid, scoped-storage

I have a navigation-like application in Google Play and I have switched to scoped storage recently.
The application needs to download the map files (to work offline) which are then rendered using the [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/) library. The files are being downloaded and loaded from `osmdroid` folder which is created on app startup by `osmdroidBasePath  = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "osmdroid").apply { mkdirs() }`. There is also a subfolder called `tiles` created by osmdroid as a cache for online tiles: `osmdroidTileCache = File(osmdroidBasePath, "tiles").apply { mkdirs() }`.

One of the users is complaining that the map files get randomly deleted after some time and he needs to download them again. I am not able to reproduce this behaviour on my device but he provided some kind of repro steps:

1. Updated the application for the latest version (12 days ago).
2. Launched the app and downloaded map files.
3. Turned the device off or didn't use the application at all (he reproduced it on multiple devices - Samsung Android 11 and Ulefone Android 10).
4. After launching the app today on both devices, neither of the devices had the map files available.

He has checked the content of the map files directory in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/app.package.name/osmdroid/ and there is only the `tiles` subfolder in there. The downloaded files are missing.

What could be the cause of the map files being deleted? I have no application logic to delete any files in the folder without the user's interaction. He claims that he doesn't use any "cleaning" apps.

Comment: please provide the way/path you are saving the files

Comment: I take the osmdroidBasePath variable to both save and read the files

Comment: Maybe this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501822/downloaded-files-get-deleted-automatically I use DownloadManager to download the maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deletion is made by DownloadIdleService as described here [Downloaded files get deleted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501822/downloaded-files-get-deleted-automatically)

I had to download the file with a temporary name (added `.download` to the end of the name), copy the file and remove the temporary one.